# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. (Sending database info from dataGridView_CellClick to another form)

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem while trying to send elements from dataGridView to the form, where I edit the whole row.

The function catches the error and displays it as "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present", but the problem is that I have rows inserted in the database, so row is not empty.

Here is the code:

```
private void urediIzbranoKnjigoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string naslovKnjige = "";
        string avtorKnjige = "";
        string datumIzdaje = "";            
        string kategorijaID = "";
        string zalozbaID = "";
        string knjiznicaID = "";
        string statusID = "";

        this.urejanje = false;

        try
        {
            this.stavekSQL = "SELECT naslovKnjige, avtorKnjige, datumIzdaje, kategorijaID, zalozbaID, knjiznicaID, statusID FROM Knjiga WHERE ID=@ID";
            this.izvediSQL = new SqlCommand(this.stavekSQL, this.povezavaDB);
            this.izvediSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", this.zadnjiIzbran);

            this.povezavaDB.Open();
            this.reader = this.izvediSQL.ExecuteReader();
            this.reader.Read();
            naslovKnjige = this.reader["naslovKnjige"].ToString();
            avtorKnjige = this.reader["avtorKnjige"].ToString();
            datumIzdaje = this.reader["datumIzdaje"].ToString();
            kategorijaID = this.reader["kategorijaID"].ToString();
            zalozbaID = this.reader["zalozbaID"].ToString();
            knjiznicaID = this.reader["knjiznicaID"].ToString();
            statusID = this.reader["statusID"].ToString();
            this.reader.Close();
            this.urejanje = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Napaka pri izvajanju: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.povezavaDB.Close();

            if (this.urejanje)
            {
                UrediKnjigo uredi = new UrediKnjigo(this, this.zadnjiIzbran, naslovKnjige, avtorKnjige, datumIzdaje, kategorijaID, zalozbaID, knjiznicaID, statusID);
                uredi.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code ? What value you have in `this.zadnjiIzbran`?

Comment: Yes I did, everything works except editing elements. this.zadnjiIzbran presents the last selected ID, by default it is -1 and when i click on the cell, the number of the row is displayed. It works as it should, If I click row 0, zadnjiIzbran gets the value 0 and so on..

Comment: What value you have in `this.zadnjiIzbran` when you get the exception ?

Comment: If I select the first row and click "edit", I get this.zadnjiIzbran + 1 so in that case 0.

Comment: So you have a row in `Knjiga` with ID=0?